# Docker Compose won't build image but tries to pull from Dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that defines multiple different services. Multiple of those services should be combined into the same image. They do refer to it in their definition. The first one has also the reference to the Dockerfile location, which should allow the build of this image. But since an update of Docker Desktop it seems to no longer be working.

The docker-compose.yml file looks something like this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    image: webapp
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app/src/frontend
    command: yarn run serve
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  backend:
    image: webapp
    command: ./run_web.sh
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXX
```

This worked perfectly fine until a few days ago, but now I get an error when trying to built the project.

```
WARNING: Some service image(s) must be built from source by running:
    docker compose build frontend
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for webapp, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

What am I missing?

The Dockerfile is not very spectacular and it builds if I simply call it manually.

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    unzip \
    apt-transport-https \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    yarn \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install pip==21.1.1 poetry==1.1.6

WORKDIR /app/src/backend


FROM base as prod

COPY src/backend/poetry.lock src/backend/poetry.toml src/backend/pyproject.toml /app/src/backend/
RUN poetry install --no-dev
COPY src/frontend/package.json src/frontend/yarn.lock /app/src/frontend/
RUN cd /app/src/frontend && yarn install --prod

COPY src/ /app/src/
```

Comment: please read this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

Comment: I have read that before, multiple times, but I am still not seeing what is going wrong. @Eitank

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile you want to build?

Comment: Have you already tried to run `docker compose build frontend` as suggested in the WARNING?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same error message

Comment: Usually when using the `build` under the service part you don't include the `image` portion because you're expected to use the image built using the dockerfile.

Comment: But I think I still need this. I want two services to be combined in the same image and therefore I need a reference. The docs state that it will simply build that image from the Dockerfile and name it using the parameters given under ```build```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've seen, that you're using the image name `webapp` in the frontend service and the backend service.

The frontend service has the build instruction included and will name the builded image webapp. The backend service does not have any build instruction and tries to pull the image `webapp` from the registry.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but I have tried adding it there as well same result. But the error message also adds the backend service into the mix.

Comment: I think this is a naming conflict between frontend and backend service. Both tries to reference the image `webapp`. I suggest you to use image `webapp_frontend` for the frontend service and image `webapp_backend` for the backend service.

Comment: I tried, even though I disagree, same result but a new image name. The whole point about me adding the image tag in them is to reference the same image. And it all worked until a couple of days ago, no changes from me.

Comment: You can disagree all you want, if both services have the same `image` tag, the service that includes a `build` directive will build the `webapp` image, and the service that specifies an image name with no `build` directive will attempt to pull whatever image name specified. If both had the same `image` directive and both built, then the second image built would crush the first one (very useless). If this ever worked, it's because you had a `webapp` image that existed on the host, you didn't need to pull it for the backend service, and now you do not.